# EF Core LINQ with conditional JOIN

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm battling to transfer a SQL statement into a linq statement for my EF Core project. I'm probably battling with the navigation properties, but it seems what I am doing in SQL - won't be possible in EF Core maybe.

I have an Transaction, which has a DebitAccount and a Credit account. A transaction is made of 1:many TransactionLines. And this is where the amount is stored. So a transaction sums up the amounts to get the transaction value.

[image]

In EF, I have defined my tables, and attempted to link them correctly with navigation properties. These are how the three tables are declared.

Account Entity:

```
internal class Account : EntityAudit
    {
        [Key, Required, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 1)]
        public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 2)]
        public AccountTypes AccountTypeId { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 3)]
        public UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 4)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Navigation Properties
        public virtual ICollection<Transaction> TransactionDebitAccount { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Transaction> TransactionCreditAccount { get; set; }


    }
```

Transaction Entity:

```
   internal class Transaction : EntityAudit
    {
        [Key, Required, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 2)]
        public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 3)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }  

        [Column(Order = 4)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 3), InverseProperty("TransactionDebitAccount")]
        public virtual Account DebitAccount { get; set; } // Nav

        [Required, Column(Order = 4), InverseProperty("TransactionCreditAccount")]
        public virtual Account CreditAccount { get; set; } // Nav

        [Required]
        public virtual List<TransactionLine> TransactionLines { get; set; } //Nav
    }
}
```

And the TransactionLine entity:

```
internal class TransactionLine
{
    [Key, Required, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(Order = 2)]
    public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; } // Nav 

    [Column(Order = 5), Range(0.01, 999999.99, ErrorMessage = "Amount must be between 0.01 and 999,999.99")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public virtual Budget Budget { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 7)]
    public virtual Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }

}
```

I am now trying to get a list of account balances. I can achieve this with a SQL statement, which uses a conditional join, and this is maybe where I am stuck on EF Core.

```
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t
ON (t.CreditAccountId = a.Id OR t.DebitAccountId = a.Id )
```

That conditional join is what is stopping me. I need to join the transactions to the account, based on one of two columns.

The whole query looks like this:

```
Select a.ExternalId AS ExternalId, a.Name, 
SUM(tl.Amount *  
case when t.CreditAccountId = a.Id then 1 
when t.DebitAccountId = a.Id then -1 end)
as Amt 
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN [Transaction] t
ON (t.CreditAccountId = a.Id OR t.DebitAccountId = a.Id )
INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl
ON tl.TransactionId = t.id
WHERE a.AccountTypeId = 1
GROUP BY a.Id, a.ExternalId, a.Name
```

I can't find a way to achieve this in EF Core using linq. Is this possible? Or would I need to restructure tables or maybe execute the SQL instead? I'd prefer to stay with EF Core / linq.

I am trying:

```
var accounts = (from a in context.Account
                                    from t in context.Transaction
                                    where t.DebitAccount.Id == a.Id || t.CreditAccount.Id == t.Id
                                    from tl in context.TransactionLine
                                    where tl.Transaction.Id == t.Id
                                    select new { a.ExternalId, a.Name })
                                    .GroupBy(x=> new { x.ExternalId, x.Name,  })
```

But failing... The 'GroupBy' isn't available to me when trying this syntax.

Comment: first of all, why don't you execute the above query from ef?

Comment: Main reason being that I like the tight connect between my code first models and the database. So, if I make a change to the model, I get design time issue to fix. When I introduce SQL, I'm worried I lose that control. I'm probably wrong though, and it might be a viable option. Would this be recommended? In this case?

Comment: Also, this page: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx - indicates I can't use Joins in a stored proc. Which seems strange.

Comment: The requirement only means you can't define a navigation property for it, but you can query the objects using LINQ alright (`from a in Account from t in Transaction where t.CreditAccountId == a.Id || t.DebitAccountId = a.Id`).

Comment: Also OR can generally be replaced by a UNION.  Just write seperate queries for debits and credits and concatenate them.

Comment: @GertArnold - Can the syntax ` var accounts = context.Account
                        .Include(x=>x...` be used in this case?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - So this can be done from linq? Make the linq query query twice? Or is the a union within linq that I can use?

Comment: No, because `Include` requires navigation properties.